# Python, Django---How can I send HTTP request in parallel with multithreading

Tags: python, django, nginx, http-request

I setup a Django + nginx + uwsgi server. In my Django application, I want to send several HTTP request in parallel. I created multiple threads and send each request in a thread. However, when I checked the time stamp at sending each request, I saw all the requests were sent sequentially.

Could anyone tell me how I can send the HTTP request in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is due to Python threads and the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) ...if you used [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threads you should be able to send them truly in parallel